# Translate Dates using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I've got a project that is hugely over budget and I'm trying to find the quickest possible solution to this.  Basically, I have a multi-lingual site that is outputting dates in the following formats in English:

- Jan 01
- January 01, 2011

Obviously there are 12 options with each month, however I only need to translate months, not days or days of the week.  Also, since I'm echoing these dates initially from PHP, the resulting HTML is 100% predictable, there will only be 24 possible returned values - 12 for Jan, Feb, Mar and 12 for January, February, March... etc.

I've already been told about the PHP `strotime()` and `setlocale()`.  I know it might be slightly janky, but is there a way to just take the PHP strings which are being spit out and translate them directly after the fact using jQuery.  What I would do is wrap the script in a PHP conditional that checks for `if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr') {}`

If there is a VERY simple way to do this through PHP I'm open to it but so far I've gotten responses from the community but they are all too time-consuming and in many cases fail to consider other variables I'm not explaining here for brevity's sake.

Also, for clarity's sake, I will say that I AM using jQuery and it's already loaded on the site.

**EDIT**

I'm not concerned about the date syntax for this, for example, it's possible for me to just do this: `if (English) { date('F j, Y');} else (FR) { date('j').' '.date('F').', '.date('Y') }`  So, my only problem is translating the month names.  Also, this is for "upcoming events" so I'm NOT trying to echo the current date/time, but a future one with a PHP timestamp.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is (it must be related to your last question but I don't get how). Are you trying to *output* dates, or *parse* them? Is the format always going to be the same (mmmm dd, yyyy)?

Comment: @Pekka - for example, it's possible for me to just do this: `if (English) { date('F j, Y');} else (FR) { date('j').' '.date('F').', '.date('Y') }`  So, my only problem is translating the months.  Also, this is for "upcoming events" so I'm NOT trying to echo the current date/time, but a future one with a PHP timestamp.

Comment: @Brian ah, sorry, I misread your question, deleted my answer

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just translate it in PHP? I see no reason why something like this should require the user to have JavaScript enabled, and JS doesn't have any native classes that make translating text any easier. PHP actually has more native string and date manipulation functions/classes. Just store the different localizations of month names in a text file and do a simple string replacement.

Comment: @Lèse majesté you're absolutely right.  I'm just clueless when it comes to PHP and can't figure out how to do this no matter how hard I try.  Honestly, I'm a total beginner with PHP and I'm thinking this particular task is over my head...

Comment: @Brian: I see. I posted an example of how it could be done without messing with `setlocale()`.

Comment: I suggest the title to be changed to "Translate Months using PHP"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Inside of mons.txt:

```
EN, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, June, July, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec
FR, janv, fevr, mars, avril, mai, juin, juil, aout, sept, oct, nov, dec
DE, Jan, Feb, Marz, Apr, Mai, Juni, Juli, Aug, Sept, Okt, Nov, Dez
IT, genn, febbr, mar, apr, magg, giugno, luglio, ag, sett, ott, nov, dic
ES, enero, feb, marzo, abr, mayo, jun, jul, agosto, set, oct, nov, dic
NL, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, Mei, Juni, Juli, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec
```

Inside of months.txt:

```
EN, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December
FR, janvier, fevrier, mars, avril, mai, juin, juillet, aout, septembre, octobre, novembre, decembre
DE, Januar, Februar, Marz, April, Mai, Juni, Juli, August, September, Oktober, November, Dezember
IT, gennaio, febbraio, marzo, aprile, maggio, giugno, luglio, agosto, settembre, ottobre, novembre, dicembre
ES, enero, febrero, marzo, abril, mayo, junio, julio, agosto, septiembre, octubre, noviembre, diciembre
NL, Januari, Februari, Maart, April, Mei, Juni, Juli, Augustus, September, Oktober, November, December
```

Inside of days.txt:

```
EN, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
FR, lundi, mardi, mercredi, jeudi, vendredi, samedi, dimanche
DE, Montag, Dienstag, Mittwoch, Donnerstag, Freitag, Samstag, Sonntag
IT, lunedi, martedi, mercoledi, giovedi, venerdi, sabato, domenica
ES, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado, domingo
NL, Maandag, Dinsdag, Woensdag, Donderdag, Vrijdag, Zaterdag, Zondag
```

To translate:

```
$date = date('l, M n, Y', strtotime('December 13th, 2012'));
$date = translate($date, 'IT');
var_dump($date);

function tmap($maps = array()) {
  $tmap = array();
  $defaultMaps = array('mons', 'months', 'ordinals', 'days', 'formats');
  $maps += $defaultMaps;
  foreach ($maps as $map) {
    $mapfile = "$map.txt";
    if (file_exists($mapfile)) {
      $file = file($mapfile);
      foreach ($file as $line) {
        $translations = str_getcsv($line);
        $locale = array_shift($translations);
        $tmap[$map][$locale] = $translations;
      }
    }
  }
  return $tmap;
}

function translate($string, $to, $classes=array(), $base='EN', $tmap=array()) {
  if (empty($tmap)) $tmap = tmap();
  if (is_string($classes)) $classes = array($classes);
  if (empty($classes)) {
    $classes = array_keys($tmap);
  }
  foreach ($classes as $class) {
    $string = str_ireplace($tmap[$class][$base], $tmap[$class][$to], $string);
  }
  return $string;
}
```

Comment: This solution uses PHP not JS

Comment: @carkod sure, but the question does talk about php throughout rather than JS

Answer (score 2):

To parse or display try it http://code.google.com/p/datejs/
Handling localization and have many types of configuration setup.

Comment: Can you give an example of using it to handle localization? I think using a well maintained FOSS library is the optimal solution, but I can't find any actual documentation on this feature (all the links to supposed i18n or L10n documentation are blank pages). Adding an example would make your answer more useful.